# MySQL fulltext index

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to set up a FULLTEXT index in an existing db table (with like 50k records), with the command below, which worked:

```
ALTER TABLE  `record_attributes` ADD FULLTEXT  `FULLTEXT` (`content_text` ,`content_varchar`)
```

Problem is, when I try to do a MATCH AGAINST on that table, it gives me this error:

```
#1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list
```

I've been searching on google and didn't find anything that I could be doing wrong. Does the index have to be added on tables without any records?

Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you search by 1 column, fulltext index by 2 columns is not matching.